# Is there a service where people can share database schemas?

Tags: database-design, schema

Does there exist a database of database schemas? I've seen a few projects online on GitLab which publish the schema but I'm not able to find any online service specifically designed for that purpose, only technical stuff comes up (e.g., *shared schema architecture*). I'd be cool though to be able to install a schema for like comments, blog, messaging quickly. Is anybody aware of any website that allows to share database schemas (possibly paid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago, there was a repository of publicly available data models.  I went back there, based on your question.  It has a different look and feel, and it appears as though it's being turned into a business.  But check it out for yourself.

https://datamodels.databases.biz/